# Can google video chat be implemented in an android app using google api

Tags: android, chat

This is my idea :
Is there gtalk api which i can use to initiate a video chat in my android app using google credentials.
Please suggest me links or any other possibility.

Or please guide me to develop an android app that can be used to voice/video chat over wifi without sip.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i was searching for the same question just to end up here with no answer! Anyway, i will share my research with you, see if this helps

1) In Intent api, there is an action called 'android.intent.action.GTALK_CONNECTED', so i think gtalk is already within android API

2) Gtalk uses Google XMPP Service.
So we can try using [Asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/), a ported Smack Library for Android

Please tell me if u make any progress and i will do the same.